# rpmlint ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/welcome.spec error

Tags: centos7

```
Name:welcome
Version:0.0.1
Release:1%{?dist}
Summary:A simple welcome script
BuildArch:noarch
License:GPL
Source0:%{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
Requires:bash
%description
A demo RPM build
%prep
%setup -q
%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_bindir}
cp %{name}.sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/%{_bindir}
%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
%files
%{_bindir}/%{name}.sh
```

I am getting this error:

```
$ rpmlint ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/welcome.spec
/home/raghu/rpmbuild/SPECS/welcome.spec: E: specfile-error error: line 2: Empty tag: Version:
/home/raghu/rpmbuild/SPECS/welcome.spec: E: specfile-error error: query of specfile /home/raghu/rpmbuild/SPECS/welcome.spec failed, can't parse
0 packages and 1 specfiles checked; 2 errors, 0 warnings.
```